# How do I unistall Tor on Windows 10?

Tags: windows

I tried searching for this question here and haven't found the specific question. I've tried uninstalling Tor on my Windows 10 laptop pc and I can't find it installed. I've gone to the usual places in the control panel, tried Revo Uninstaller to search for it and looked for it in CCleaner. I even tried looking for it in the command line and looked for folders where it would be installed. Nothing.

However, I can launch it using the desktop icon or in the start menu and open the browser.

Any ideas how to find and uninstall this browser? Thanks.

Comment: Just delete its folder and its shortcuts (if any). Doing it will completely removed from your pc.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I sent the same question to the Tor Project, but I got a robot and was sent back instruction how to install it. While using Tor it does hide the location and IP address and it even sends a message to update the software. It warns not to go full screen for while in that mode, it is possible that your computer may be identified. While it bounces you round the globe, it slows down and often gives the dreaded spinning circle for ages and extreme stuttering when it finds the website.

Answer (score 3):

Tor is not installing *any* registry information and nothing but it's files, so just deleting the folder with Tor and the shortcuts from your desktop(if you have ones) will remove it. No traces in system will be left

Comment: Thank you. I figured that out and ran Revo Installer, found the files and deleted them all. I appreciate your help.